# Query for updating a table value based on the total of a column found in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query to sum all the prc values from different tables and UPDATE it to main_trans.tot.

ex. tot value for TR01 should be 30 adding all TR01 prcs from two tables.

Table main_trans:

```
| id | tot | 
|TR01|  30 |
|TR02|  5  |
```

TABLE sub_trans_a:

```
| id | prc |
|TR01|  10 |
|TR01|  10 |
```

TABLE sub_trans_b:

```
| id | prc |
|TR01|  10 |
|TR02|  5  |
```

I don't know how to write it so that it would automatically update all rows based on their id. So far, my query does the work if i specifically write the value of the id column:

```
UPDATE main_trans  SET tot =  
(SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_a WHERE id = 'TR01')
+ (SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_b WHERE id = 'TR01') 
WHERE id = 'TR01'
```

Comment: As a side note, it's often better to calculate these values every time you need them.  Having a `sum` in another table always causes consistency issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join in your update query with a union set

```
UPDATE main_trans m  
join
(SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc
FROM (
SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc FROM sub_trans_a WHERE id = 'TR01'
union all
SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc FROM sub_trans_b WHERE id = 'TR01'
) t1
) t
on(t.id = m.id)
SET m.tot = t.prc 
WHERE m.id = 'TR01'
```

Also if you have same structure for `sub_trans_a` and `sub_trans_a` so why 2 tables why not just a single table or with a single column for the type as type a or type b

### [`See Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb76c6/1)

Or if you want to update your whole `main_trans` table without providing id values you can do so by adding a group by in query

```
UPDATE main_trans m  
join
(SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc
FROM (
SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc FROM sub_trans_a group by id
union all
SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc FROM sub_trans_b group by id
) t1  group by id
) t
on(t.id = m.id)
SET m.tot = t.prc
```

### [`See Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d1f72/1)

Edit a good suggestion by **[Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50552/andomar)** you can simplify inner query as

```
UPDATE main_trans m  
join
(SELECT id,SUM(prc) prc
FROM (
SELECT id,prc FROM sub_trans_a
union all
SELECT id,prc FROM sub_trans_b 
) t1 WHERE id = 'TR01'
) t
on(t.id = m.id)
SET m.tot = t.prc 
WHERE m.id = 'TR01'
```

Comment: @Andomar no just for a style to  highlight demo :)

Comment: You could omit the inner `sum` and move `WHERE id = 'TR01'` outside the first subquery.  Also `on t.id = m.id` seems clearer than `on(t.id = m.id)`

Comment: @Andomar yes that is a good suggestion thanks for correcting me

Comment: Thanks you for the clear explanation and multiple options! I got what I need and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the update for all at the same time, just use correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE main_trans mt
    SET tot = ( (SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_a a WHERE a.id = mt.id) +
                (SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_b b WHERE b.id = mt.id) 
              );
```

If one or both tables may not have values, then the result might be `NULL`.  You can fix this using `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE main_trans mt
    SET tot = ( COALESCE((SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_a a WHERE a.id = mt.id), 0) +
                COALESCE((SELECT SUM(prc) FROM sub_trans_b b WHERE b.id = mt.id), 0)
              );
```